# Deserialize array of objects inside another object using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

Using Volley in my Android project, I am getting a json response like:

```
{
    "value1": 1,
    "value2": aaa,
    "subvalues": [
    {
        "value1": 297,
        "value2": 310,
        "class3": {
            "name": "name1",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 32            
          }
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

I need to deserialize it to pojo using Gson. Classes are:

class1:

```
public class class1 {
    private int value1;
    private String value2;
    private List<class2> vals;

    public class class2 {
        private int value1;
        private int value2;
        private class3 c3;
   }
}
```

class3:

```
public class class3 {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int value;
}
```

After calling

```
Gson g = new Gson();
class1 c1 = g.fromJson(jsonString, class1.class);
```

I have only `value1` and `value2` of `class1` filled. List remains `null` all the time.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change  `private List<class2> vals;` to `private List<class2> subvalues`

Answer (score 6):

You need to change:

```
private List<class2> vals;
```

to:

```
private List<class2> subvalues;
```

If you would like to keep `vals` field original name you can use [SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation:

```
public class class1 {
    private int value1;
    private String value2;

    @SerializedName("subvalues")
    private List<class2> vals;

    ...
}
```

[Here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/) you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in JSON your referring as `subvalues` and in java object your field name as `vals`. change it to `subvalues` it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state, you're not naming your variables correctly for gson to be able to deserialize properly. Note that you seemingly have a typo in your returned json as well in class two, referring to `calss3` instead of class3.